# Efficient way to group this ruby array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enumerable

I have an array of instances of model `Foo`. `Foo` is an Ohm based data store. Each instance of `Foo` has `an_id` and integer attributes such as `follows`, `likes`. If there are two instances of `Foo` with the same `an_id`, I'd love to add the `follows` and `likes` attributes together. The solution I had was to create a hash where each key is an `an_id` of the array, and keep the state there. If the array is large enough, this is not efficient as I need each object back into an array. I'd love to group the array by `Foo#an_id` and merge/add the counter attributes together and pop that back into the array. Is something like this currently supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [sum](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/sum)

As a start, something like this:

```
grouped_hash = your_array.group_by(&:an_id)
sums_by_id = {}
grouped_hash.each do |id,values|
  sums_by_id[id] = {}
  # you could also just iterate over values once and += :follows and :likes
  sums_by_id[id][:follows] = values.sum(&:follows)
  sums_by_id[id][:likes]   = values.sum(&:likes)
end
```

Example output:
    sums_by_id => {1 => {:follows => 2, :likes => 4}, 2 => ...

Additionally, take a look at:

[inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

```
(5..10).inject {|sum, n| sum + n }  # 45
```

Comment: I think the problem with the solution above is I need this back into an array so I can perform a sort operation. Ideally I'd like to sort by follows/likes etc. Is there a trivial way to do so using the data structure you built above?

Comment: sums_by_id.to_a.sort_by {| obj | block } → array

Comment: You might want to consider doing this in the database. Model.where(:some_id_attr => an_id).all.order('follows DESC'), or use active record :group and :sum

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inject` to get a sum of values:

```
array = *array of Foo*
total = array.inject { |sum, x| sum + x.likes }
```